# How to prevent boolean type juggling to int in PHP

Tags: php, types, casting, boolean

Hey I'm learning PHP and I'm finding the type juggling to be a complete nightmare.
I was playing with iterables and noticed that instead `TRUE` or `FALSE` I got `1` and `0`.

A **small** example:

```
<?php
class MyIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $var = array();

    public function __construct($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $this->var = $array;
        }
    }

        public function valid()
    {
        $key = key($this->var);
        $var = ($key !== NULL && $key !== FALSE);
        print_r("valid: ". $var ."\n<br />");
        return $var;
    }

}

$values = array(1,2,3);
$it = new MyIterator($values);

foreach ($it as $a => $b) {
    print "$a: $b\n<br />";
}
```

In bigger arrays or chunks of code this kind of output becomes really confusing is there a way to force PHP to dump `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of `1` and `0`?

Comment: Can you explain how this notation is confusing? Php allows comparison of these different types and if you need the literal printed a simple ternary statement can accomplish that.

Comment: What confuses me is the juggling not the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast using `(bool)` or `(boolean)` operators, but you should rarely need to do this as PHP will cast automatically if it sees an operation that requires a boolean.

If you `echo` or `print` a boolean it will never output `TRUE` or `FALSE`  it will be converted to an `int` and display `1` or `0`. You can however use `var_dump((bool)$val)` that will output `bool(false)` or `bool(true)` which can give you a better idea of how the boolean will be converted.

Comment: Is there anyway to force that into a print or an echo?

Comment: @MiguelM `var_dump` will output that